# Filter data from zipped databases in python

Tags: python, database, zip

I have a following problem. I have two large databases. The first database is called an_visit_ab. It is large and zipped as an_visit_ab.sql.bz2. The second database is large too, but I am able to store it on my computer as an_visit.db.

Structure of databases:

`an_visit_ab` is ordered by `visit_id` in ascending order:

```
visit_id    ab_test_id  variant
594817698   1   0
594817704   1   1
594817705   1   1
594817706   1   0
594817709   1   0
```

`an_visit` is ordered by `visit_id` in ascending order, too:

```
visit_id    datetime_add    is_bot
1   2017-06-21 18:10:38 0
3   2017-06-21 18:10:39 1
```

I need to filter out from `an_visit_ab` all `visit_id` where `is_bot` is 1 in `an_visit`. Normally, I would to a simple JOIN in SQL. But because I am not able to even unzip `an_visit_ab.sql.bz2` I need a different strategy.

What I came with until now:

1. I need to read `an_visit_ab.sql.bz2` line by line. Because both databases are ordered by `visit_id`, I can look to the `an_visit` to a corresponding `visit_id` and check if `is_bot` is 1.
2. I do it in python. I have a following code that reads `an_visit_ab.sql.bz2` line by line:

```py
from bz2 import BZ2File as bzopen

AN_VISIT_AB = "an_visit_ab.sql.bz2"

with bzopen(AN_VISIT_AB, "r") as bzfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(bzfile):
        print(line)
```

The output looks like this:

```
b'-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64)\n'
b'--\n'
b'-- Host: localhost    Database: XXX\n'
b'-- ------------------------------------------------------\n'
b'-- Server version\t5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1\n'
b'\n'
b'/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\n'
b'/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\n'
b'/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;\n'
b'/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;\n'
b'/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;\n'
b"/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;\n"
b'/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;\n'
b'/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;\n'
b"/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;\n"
b'/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;\n'
b'\n'
b'--\n'
b'-- Table structure for table `an_visit_ab`\n'
b'--\n'
b'\n'
b'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `an_visit_ab`;\n'
b'/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;\n'
b'/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;\n'
b'CREATE TABLE `an_visit_ab` (\n'
b'  `visit_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,\n'
b'  `ab_test_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,\n'
b'  `variant` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,\n'
b'  PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`,`ab_test_id`,`variant`),\n'
b'  UNIQUE KEY `visit_id_ab_test_id` (`visit_id`,`ab_test_id`),\n'
b'  KEY `ab_test_id_ab_test_variant` (`ab_test_id`,`variant`),\n'
b'  KEY `ab_test_id` (`ab_test_id`),\n'
b'  CONSTRAINT `an_visit_ab_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`visit_id`) REFERENCES `an_visit` (`visit_id`),\n'
b'  CONSTRAINT `an_visit_ab_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`ab_test_id`, `variant`) REFERENCES `an_new_ab_test_variant` (`ab_test_id`, `variant`)\n'
b') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;\n'
b'/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;\n'
b'\n'
b'--\n'
b'-- Dumping data for table `an_visit_ab`\n'
b'--\n'
b'\n'
b'LOCK TABLES `an_visit_ab` WRITE;\n'
b'/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `an_visit_ab` DISABLE KEYS */;\n'

(594878944,1,1),(594878945,1,0),(594878946,1,0),(594878947,1,1),(594878948,1,0),(594878949,1,1),(594878950,1,0),(594878951,1,0),(594878952,1,1),(594878953,1,1),(594878954,1,1),(594878955,1,1),(594878956,1,0),(594878957,1,1),(594878958,1,1),(594878959,1,1),(594878960,1,0),(594878961,1,0),(594878962,1,0),(594878963,1,1),(594878964,1,1),(594878965,1,0),(594878966,1,1),(594878967,1,0),(594878968,1,1),(594878969,1,1),(594878970,1,1),(594878971,1,0),(594878972,1,1),(594878973,1,0),(594878974,1,0),(594878975,1,1),(594878976,1,1),(594878977,1,0),(594878978,1,1),(594878979,1,1),(594878980,1,0),(594878981,1,1),(594878982,1,1),(594878983,1,0),(594878984,1,1),(594878985,1,1),(594878986,1,0),(594878987,1,1),(594878988,1,1),(594878989,1,0),(594878990,1,1),(594878991,1,0),(594878992,1,0),(594878993,1,1),(594878994,1,0),(594878995,1,1),(594878996,1,1),(594878997,1,1),(594878998,1,1),(594878999,1,0),(594879000,1,0),(594879001,1,0),(594879002,1,0),(594879003,1,0),(594879004,1,1),(594879005,1,1),(594879006,1,0),(594879007,1,1),(594879008,1,1),(594879009,1,1),(594879010,1,0),(594879011,1,1),(594879012,1,1),(594879013,1,0),(594879014,1,0),(594879015,1,0),(594879016,1,1),(594879017,1,0),(594879018,1,0),(594879019,1,1),(594879020,1,1),(594879021,1,1),(594879022,1,1),(594879023,1,0),(594879024,1,1),(594879025,1,0),(594879026,1,0),(594879027,1,1),(594879028,1,0),(594879029,1,1),(594879030,1,0),(594879031,1,1),(594879032,1,0),(594879033,1,1),(594879034,1,1),(594879035,1,0),(594879036,1,1),(594879037,1,1),(594879038,1,0),(594879039,1,1),(594879040,1,1),(594879041,1,1),(594879042,1,1),(594879043,1,0),(594879044,1,0),(594879045,1,0),(594879046,1,0),(594879047,1,1),(594879048,1,0),(594879049,1,1),(594879050,1,0),(594879051,1,1),(594879052,1,1),(594879053,1,1),(594879054,1,0),(594879055,1,1),(594879056,1,0),(594879057,1,0),(594879058,1,0),(594879059,1,0),(594879060,1,1),(594879061,1,1),(594879062,1,0),(594879063,1,0),(594879064,1,0),(594879065,1,1),(594879066,1,1),(594879067,1,0),(594879068,1,1),(594879069,1,0),(594879070,1,0),(594879071,1,0),(594879072,1,0),(594879073,1,0),(594879074,1,0),(594879075,1,0),(594879076,1,0),(594879077,1,0),(594879078,1,1),(594879079,1,1),(594879080,1,1),(594879081,1,1),(594879082,1,1),(594879083,1,0),(594879084,1,0),(594879085,1,0),(594879086,1,0),(594879087,1,1),(594879088,1,1),(594879089,1,0),(594879090,1,1),(594879091,1,0),(594879092,1,1),(594879093,1,0),(594879094,1,0),(594879095,1,0),(594879096,1,1),(594879097,1,1),(594879098,1,0),(594879099,1,1),(594879100,1,0),(594879101,1,1),(594879102,1,1),(594879103,1,0),(594879104,1,0),(594879105,1,1),(594879106,1,1),(594879107,1,0),(594879108,1,1),(594879109,1,1),(594879110,1,0),(594879111,1,1),(594879112,1,1),(594879113,1,0),(594879114,1,0),(594879115,1,1),(594879116,1,1),(594879117,1,1),(594879118,1,1),(594879119,1,0),(594879120,1,1),(594879121,1,1),(594879122,1,0),(594879123,1,1),(594879124,1,1),(594879125,1,0),(594879126,1,1),(594879127,1,1),(594879128,1,1),(594879129,1,1),(594879130,1,0),(594879131,1,1),(594879132,1,0),(594879133,1,0),(594879134,1,0),(594879135,1,1),(594879136,1,0),(594879137,1,0),(594879138,1,0),(594879139,1,1),(594879140,1,1),(594879141,1,0),(594879142,1,0),(594879143,1,1),(594879144,1,0),(594879145,1,0),(594879146,1,1),(594879147,1,0),(594879148,1,0),(594879149,1,1),(594879150,1,0),(594879151,1,0),(594879152,1,0),(594879153,1,1),(594879154,1,1),(594879155,1,1),(594879156,1,1),(594879157,1,1),(594879158,1,1),(594879159,1,1),(594879160,1,1),(594879161,1,0),(594879162,1,1),(594879163,1,1),(594879164,1,0),(594879165,1,0),(594879166,1,0),(594879167,1,1),(594879168,1,1),(594879169,1,1),(594879170,1,0),(594879171,1,0),(594879172,1,1),(594879173,1,0),(594879174,1,1),(594879175,1,1),(594879176,1,1),(594879177,1,0),(594879178,1,1),(594879179,1,1),(594879180,1,0),(594879181,1,1),(594879182,1,0),(594879183,1,1),(594879184,1,0),(594879185,1,0),(594879186,1,0),(594879187,1,1),(594879188,1,0),(594879189,1,0),(594879190,1,1),(594879191,1,0),(594879192,1,0),(594879193,1,1),(594879194,1,1),(594879195,1,1),(594879196,1,1),(594879197,1,1),(594879198,1,0),(594879199,1,1),(594879200,1,1),(594879201,1,0),(594879202,1,0),(594879203,1,0),(594879204,1,1),(594879205,1,1),(594879206,1,1),(594879207,1,0),(594879208,1,1),(594879209,1,1),(594879210,1,1),(594879211,1,0),(594879212,1,0),(594879213,1,0),(594879214,1,0),(594879215,1,0),(594879216,1,1),(594879217,1,1),(594879218,1,0),(594879219,1,1),(594879220,1,0),(594879221,1,1),(594879222,1,0),(594879223,1,0),(594879224,1,1),(594879225,1,1),(594879226,1,0),(594879227,1,0),(594879228,1,0),(594879229,1,1),(594879230,1,1),(594879231,1,1),(594879232,1,1),(594879233,1,1),(594879234,1,0),(594879235,1,0),(594879236,1,0),(594879237,1,1),(594879238,1,0),(594879239,1,0),(594879240,1,0),(594879241,1,1),(594879242,1,0),(594879243,1,0),(594879244,1,1),(594879245,1,0),(594879246,1,1),(594879247,1,0),(594879248,1,1),(594879249,1,1),(594879250,1,0),(594879251,1,0),(594879252,1,1),(594879253,1,0),(594879254,1,1),(594879255,1,0),(594879256,1,0),(594879257,1,1),(594879258,1,1),(594879259,1,1),(594879260,1,0),(594879261,1,1),(594879262,1,0),(594879263,1,0),(594879264,1,0);\n'
```

But I got stuck here and I don`t know how to continue. I would like to ask you:

1. Is my strategy good? Or is there something better than reading it line by line?
2. Can you show me, how can I filter is_bot from `an_visit_ab.sql.bz2` as I have tried above?

Please, if there is something unclear in my question, do not downgrade immediately and give my chance to explain it more preciously :-). Thanks

Comment: What is unclear to me is what you want as your output. Is it another MySQL dump with those rows removed? Should it be a compressed file?

Comment: @Booboo Output should be a compressed file

Comment: You only answered the second of my two questions but I shall assume that you also intend it to be in MySQL dump format. How large of a dataset is this **uncompressed**? And can I assume the second file is also a MySQL dump? **This is 2 questions**.

Comment: Sorry, yes it should my .db or .sql (I don`t really care) and compressed. The second file is also MySQL dump. `an_visit_ab.sql.bz2` unzipped have about 1TB

Comment: Is your strategy good? You have demonstrated that you can read a compressed file line by line., which is a good start but by itself it is not sufficient to solve your problem. Have you considered hiring a consultant?

Comment: @Booboo no, I ask on stackoverflow and offer you a bounty, lol

Comment: I could outline something for you but it may not be enough for you to turn into working code. It would be helpful if you included a bit more of the MySQL dump so I could see the start of statement that dumps the table, i.e. the INSERT or WRITE statement or whatever it is using and a couple of subsequent lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**: Here is an example of how you could first process the second MySQL dump, **an_visit.db** by reading it in line by line and creating a `set` of **visit_id** entries that have **is_bot** set to 1, assuming there are not so many such entries that the set could not fit into memory. I am assuming that the MySQL dump has been created with an INSERT INTO statement with the column names mentioned once and the row values separated by commas and split across multiple lines (you have not printed enough of the dump as asked to verify this):

```py
def create_id_set():
    """
    Create a set of visit_id values whose is_bot value is 1.
    """

    id_set = set()
    state = 0
    # I am assuming that the file is not compressed.
    # If the file is compressed, then replace the regular call to open with:
    # with bz2.open('an.visit.db', 'rt') as f:
    with open('an_visit.db') as f:
        for line in f:
            if state == 0: # We have not seen the INSERT statement yet
                if line.startswith('INSERT INTO'):
                    state = 1
            elif state == 1: # We are processing the rows:
                line = line.strip()
                if line.endswith(';'):
                    state = 2 # Our next state
                    line = line.rstrip(';')
                else:
                    line.rstrip(',')
                line = line.replace('),(', ')|(') # Replace so we can split
                values_list = line.split('|')
                for row in values_list:
                    columns = row[1:-1].split(', ') # Skip outer parentheses
                    if columns[2] == '1': # is_bot is 1?
                        id_set.add(columns[0]) # Add visit_id
            elif state == 2: # We are done
                return id_set

id_set = create_id_set()
```

If there are too many entries to create a set, then I would turn this function into a generator that yields the next **visit_id**. Then in Step 2, described below, you will be iterating this iterator in parallel, which makes the next step slightly more complicated.

**Step 2**: Once you have that set, you need to now open for input (preferably in text mode using `bz2.open(path, 'rt')`) the first MySQL dump and a second **bz2** compressed output file that will contain the filtered output (you cannot update in place), also in text mode using flags 'wt'). Using logic similar to what I used in Step 1, you will need to read in each line and writing out the output of all lines up to and including the INSERT INTO statement and all lines following the last row value (state == 2). You need to alter the logic by saving the original row value including the opening and closing parentheses that enclose the comma-separated values before splitting. You will then test the **visit_id** value against the `set` returned in Step 1 to determine whether this row value should be outputted. You will need to output either a comma or a semicolon following this row value depending on whether this is the final row value or not being output. You should also write a newline after writing every N values.